# How to find which button was clicked from a list of 20 buttons?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have on my page 20 buttons (start and stop) each start and stop belongs to an specific div and should initiate a timer over there only.

I need to identify when the start button was clicked and to know from where it was clicked.

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button"); //returns a HTMLCollection
for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++)
{
   buttons[i].addEventListener("click", function()   {buttonsControl(buttons);}, false);
}

function buttonsControl(buttons)
{
  alert(buttons[2].innerHTML);
}
```

I tried passing `i` as argument alone and it returns always the last index of the array. 
After I tried sending the whole array and i together but it does not work, I get:

`TypeError: buttons[i] is undefined`

How could I identify exactly which button was clicked?

**EDIT**

html

```
        <div class="timer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary start">start</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger stop">stop</button>
        </div>
```

Comment: add the html of the buttons, are there any id's, classes attributes?

Comment: They must be associated with something that has unique information, so show us that and we can help.

Comment: Just do all the stuff relative to the clicked button (`this`).

Comment: you can use the data attribute, numeric each button with different value, and then check its value when clicked

Comment: acutally, it returns HTMLCollection not NodeList

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare as `let` your variable `i`

```
for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
     ^
```

```js
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button"); //returns a nodelist
for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  buttons[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    buttonsControl(this, i);
  }, false);
}

function buttonsControl(button, i) {
  console.log(i);
  console.log(button.className);
}
```

```html
<div class="timer">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary start">start</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger stop">stop</button>
</div>
```

## Resource

- [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let)

  > The `let` statement declares a block scope local variable, optionally initializing it to a value.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```js
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button"); //returns a 
Array.from(buttons).forEach((ele, index) => ele.addEventListener("click", function() {
  alert('you click button ' + index)
}, false))
```

```html
<div class="timer">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary start">start</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger stop">stop</button>
</div>
```

Comment: @Andreas,agree with you ,however i tried buttons.forEach at the begining,i got error,,,,After i checked,i found getElementsByTagName returns HTMLCollection not NodeList,,,,

Comment: Ups... I've got `.getElementsByTagName()` and `.querySelectorAll()` mixed up - Never mind^^

Answer (score 1):

You can target clicked button by event of javascript.

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button"); //returns a nodelist
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
   buttons[i].addEventListener("click", function(event) {
     buttonsControl(event.target);
   }, false);
}

function buttonsControl(button) {
 alert(button.innerHTML);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can catch the value id class etc with this

```js
function btn(e){
alert(e.value);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="btn(this)" value="btn1">button1</button>
<button onclick="btn(this)" value="btn2">button2</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this worked well, i2 lets you see the index and see what button
is clicked. unsure if its up to standard but it works

```
function findindex(i2){
  alert(i2); // lets you see what index of button was clicked
}

for(i = 0; i < btnClass.length; i++){ 
      let i2 = i; //stores the same value, but avoids error you originally got
      btnClass[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
      findindex(i2)
    });
  }
```